# Android Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

can any say that how can i view image in another activity when click on the particular image with description

Here is the java file

```
package course.examples.UI.GridLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class GridLayoutActivity extends Activity {

protected static final String EXTRA_RES_ID = "POS";

private int[]  mThumbIdsFlowers = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4,            

      R.drawable.image5,
                R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7,   

      R.drawable.image8,
                R.drawable.image9, R.drawable.image10,   

    R.drawable.image11,
                R.drawable.image12};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     String[] description=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);
    GridView gridview=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, mThumbIdsFlowers,description));


}
    }
```

**Custom Adapter**

```
 package course.examples.UI.GridLayout;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.zip.Inflater;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final int PADDING = 8;
    private static final int WIDTH = 50;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 50;
    private Context mContext;
    private int[] mThumbIds;
    private String[] description;
    ArrayList<row_item> arraylist;
    class row_item{
     int img;
     String description;
    row_item(int img,String description){
        this.img=img;
        this.description=description;

    }

     }
    public ImageAdapter(Context c, int[] img,String[] description) {
        mContext = c;
        this.mThumbIds =img;
        this.description=description;
        this.arraylist=new ArrayList<row_item>();
        for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
        {
            arraylist.add(new row_item(img[i], description[i]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    // Will get called to provide the ID that
    // is passed to OnItemClickListener.onItemClick()


    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService
                  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_style,null);
        ImageView img=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        TextView text=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        img.setImageResource(arraylist.get(position).img);
        text.setText(arraylist.get(position).description);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
        }
```

I am trying to set layout using the baseadapter class .I am storing the description and image id in the arraylist then I am setting ImageView and TextView from the ArrayList .It is giving runtime error.

here is logcat msg

```
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): Process: course.examples.UI.GridLayout, PID: 1322
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{course.examples.UI.GridLayout/course.examples.UI.GridLayout.GridLayoutActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at course.examples.UI.GridLayout.GridLayoutActivity.<init>(GridLayoutActivity.java:24)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
06-08 02:22:29.516: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     ... 11 more
06-08 02:22:34.556: I/Process(1322): Sending signal. PID: 1322 SIG: 9
```

here is layout xml file 
row_style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/img"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is main.xml in layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   ></GridView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

here is mainfest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="course.examples.UI.GridLayout"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".GridLayoutActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ImageViewActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
            </action>

            <data
                android:mimeType="image/*"
                android:scheme="android.resource" >
            </data>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>
          </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     </application>
   </manifest>
```

Comment: Which error?Please post logcat exception also.

Comment: Did you add GridLayoutActivity  in manifest file? please post manifest.xml file

Comment: post your manifest file also

Comment: yaa it has been solved

Comment: can u tell me how can i see the image onclick particular image

Comment: this post may help you  (second answer )http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738817/create-a-clickable-image-in-a-gridview-in-android

Comment: i want in another activity

Comment: post your problem as new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace points to this line as the source of the exception:

```
private String[] description=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);
```

The inherited `getResources()` method is throwing an exception. That's because you can't call `getResources()` until later, after the activity is constructed and initialized. Move those member variable initializations into `onCreate()` and you should be good to go.

Simply  Change

```
private String[] description=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

to

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
String[] description=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);
```